# Application to FTP files from windows server

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.NET MVC website which clients post files to as part of an order process. These files can be up to 200MB. I have a need to transfer these files to another server via FTP. I don't really want to burden IIS with this. So was thinking of writing c# app to handle the file transfer which ran every x minutes and use windows service to run it.

Would this be an ok solution or is there something that could handle this for me already?

If I wrote the application should I let windows service handle the scheduling i.e. start the app every x minutes or should I just get it start the app on say startup and let the app handle the sleep/wakeup.

I was envisaging something quite rudimentary. Using SQL to track what needs uploading and has been uploaded. Are there any other considerations particular to a window service?

The website runs on iis8 on a windows 2012 vps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One architecture tip -- use a simple executable and a scheduled task rather than write a service. You don't need to worry about memory leakage over months then.

You could probably implement this without writing any code -- you can [script ftp.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555976) pretty effectively. I'd just script it to push all the files, and then, presuming FTP.EXE exited with 0, to clean out the uploads folder and rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks and good tip and I suppose was sort of what I was getting at. If I schedule a task can I get it start after the previous task had finished for x amount of time. I had also thought of using a script but wanted to log things in sql server so I could view what had happened from an admin website. I presume I could do this in PS but thought it would be better in an ap..

Comment: Powershell is amazingly powerful, you can write full blown multi-threaded apps if you are crazy enough.